# RAils 3.1 Why does this query work in development but not in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sqlite

note: finishDate is a field in Events table

This query works fine in development

```
def reminders
  @events = @user.events.find(:all, :conditions=> ['finishDate >= ?', Time.now])
end
```

but throws this error in production

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "finishdate" does not exist
LINE 1: ...vent_id" WHERE "events_users"."user_id" = 13 AND (finishDate...
                                                             ^
```

heroko console

```
>> Event.last.finishDate
=> Tue, 10 Apr 2012 19:05:00 UTC +00:00
```

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the table column from

```
finishDate
```

to

```
finish_date
```

and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your table does not have such a column as "finishDate." Are you sure that both tables (if there are two) are identical? Maybe you made some changes manually and have not been introduced to an array of production.

Besides, a lot more helpful would be a full SQL query that is displayed next to the summary of the selected error.

Comment: I edited the question with the output of heroku console. It looks like there is a finishDate column. You might be right about using full SQL query. However, do not know how to do it.

Comment: Could it be because of using camel letters => finishDate. Instead of finish_date?